# Adding data under specific header in a 2D vector array

Tags: c++

Imagine that we have a data such as:

```
1A
1 
Hi World
2A
2
Hello Bob
Life is Good
3A
0
```

The data has an tags ***1A,2A,3A*** which is the main tag. Under that tag it shows the number of strings in that tab i.e ***1,2,0*** , followed by the strings. How can we display the data on the screen such that we show the main tag and the strings under it respectively?.

The code:

```
vector<string> class_names;
vector<string> data;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("file.txt");
    string line;
    for (int lineno = 1; getline(myfile, line); lineno++) {
        if (lineno == 1 || lineno == 4 || lineno == 8) {
            class_names.push_back(line); // stores the class names
        }
        else if (lineno != 2 && lineno != 5 && lineno != 9) {
            data.push_back(line);   // stores the data in classes
        }
    }
```

What I have done is here is store the data from the file in vectors and they can be printed separately but I cant add another class to this file? How can we have this data in a single vector or 2D vector such that the user can put the data in 1A or even create a new data tab like 4A ? How would that be done?

For example the user would need to enter **How are you** in 1A , how? I am not being about to come up with a solution to this in code as I am quite a beginner.

Comment: Write a function to do that. Print the heading, then the data in your function. Maybe you should show what you have tried. I am having a difficulty to guess where you are having problems with this task. [mcve]

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried my best to explain it but actually the I am not being able to get in code as I have no idea regarding it, I hope its a bit understandable else I can help explain it more/

Comment: @CanceR227 Please post the data as text, not as an image.  If someone were to try and duplicate the issue (or even attempt to post an answer), they have to convert that image to text, just to get the program started.

Comment: This may be easier if you read them into a data structure that has the structure you want already baked in. I'm thinking you want to store them in map<string, vector<string>> where the key is the header tag. You then append the lines to that tag's collection. (although maybe just vector of struct, if you want to preserve their original order) I also agree with the first comment - you describe many tasks; need a function to handle each.

Comment: Your question mentions a 2d array, but your code doesn't. Do you just not know how to create the data structure?

Comment: I know how to create a 2D array but lets say after creating it what to do? How to push data such that it contains a specific data , like the 1A header is at [0][0] and then data it contains starts from [0][1]. I am not being able to understand completely how to able to do that? Sorry I am a newbie in this programming field.

Answer (score 0):

One way of thinking is "how would I do this without a computer?".

There are two kinds of info:

1. The tag. Each tag is used to difference from other group of data. It can be a string, or an int, or whatever.
2. The data itself. There are groups of data, associated each on with a
   unique tag. The size of the group is variable.

So, having a "folder" which stores all tags and also the data may be tricky, just because how do you search for a specific tag?

 We could store the tag, followed by the data. Because the size of data (number of strings) is variable, we need another value for each tag: the size of data. This is actually what the input file contains.

C++ does not like storing different types in the same container. So, even our "unique folder" seemed a good idea, it's not that good in C++ if tags and data are of different types.

There's a C++ thing called `std::variant` which can contain different types of data in the same variable. But, since you are a begginer, let's start with something simpler.

So better we use a container for tags and other container for data, so as each container has the same type for its items. Then we also need a relation between tags and data, between both containers.

For the relation we can use the container `std::map`. It uses, for each entry, an identifier (the tag) and an index to the data associated with that tag.

Again, we can do it with simpler containers. We can use `std::array`, but it has the issue of it's fixed size, we can not add new items, unless you declare the array of a size enough for all cases. Likely a waste of space, useful only when you know the size in advance.

The best is to use `std::vector`. We can have a "vector of tags" and another "vector of user-strings".

The relation can be simple: the index of the tag in the first container is the same index as in the data container. If tag "3B" is located at `tagVector[4]` then the group of strings for this tag is placed at `dataVector[4]`.

Good, but how do we storing "groups" of strings? Easy: a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`

So, adding a new tag is as easy as

```
std::vector<Tag> tagVector; //say 'Tag' is a class or a simple type
tagVector.push_back(newtag); //newtag is a 'Tag' type object obtained some where else
```

Adding a string for that tag requires:

 a) Finding the index:

```
auto index = std::find(std::begin(tagVector), std::end(tagVector), newtag);
```

b) Adding the string:

```
//std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> dataVector; //already done before
dataVector.at(index).push_back(theNewString);
```

The number of items in the group for that tag is

```
auto nuItems = dataVector.at(index).size();
```

CAN WE USE A 2D ARRAY?

Well, some how. If all items are of the same type, let's say 'string'.

A 2D array is an array of 1D arrays. A `NxM` size array means you can have at most 'N' tags, and at most 'M-1' data-items for each tag, because we reserve, for example, the first column for the tags. The rest of cells are empty.

To find a tag you must search each of `arr[i][0]`.

Once you have `i` you can search for the last data item: first of `arr[i][k]` that is empty, with `k < M-1`.

To store a new data, just replace this `arr[i][k]`, if there's room yet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better answers is that you should use a "more-modern" object oriented approach with C++.

So, you will put the data, together with the member functions to operate on the data, into a class/struct.

So, we will put the "tag" and "texts" (defined as a `std::vector<std::string>`) into a class. The number of texts is inherently stored in the vector, so we do not need an additional member variable for that.

For output (inserting into a stream) we overwite the inserter operator. And simply write everything, as expected, to the output stream.

For the texts we use the `std::ostream_iterator`. Together with the `std::copy` we will iterate over all texts and call ther >> operator for every text.

The extractor operator is a little bit more complicated. First, we read a line and interprete the content as the tag. Next, we will read an unsigned integer number for the count of the follwing texts. And last but not least, we read the texts in a loop. All the results will be stored into our structs member variables.

With this mechanism we could write now something like:

```
TagAndTexts tt{};
std::cin >> tt;
std::cout << tt;
```

In main, we first open the source file and then use the `std::istream_iterator` to call the >> of the "TagAndTexts", until all entries are read.

We store all data in a `std::vector`, using its range constructor. Then we show everything on `std::cout`.

We will get a new entry from the user, show all data on the screen, and store the new data into the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct TagAndTexts {
    // The tag
    std::string tag{};
    // And the texts associated with the tag
    std::vector<std::string> texts{};

    // Overwrite Inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TagAndTexts& tat) {
        // Simply output data in expected format
        os << tat.tag << "\n" << tat.texts.size() << "\n";
        // Write texts
        std::copy(tat.texts.begin(), tat.texts.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }

    // Overwrite extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TagAndTexts& tat) {
        // Read the tag
        if (std::string line; std::getline(is, line)) {
            // Read the text Count
            if (std::string textCount{}; std::getline(is, textCount)) {
                std::istringstream iss(textCount); 
                // And read all texts
                tat.tag = line; tat.texts.clear();
                if (unsigned max{}; iss >> max)
                for (size_t i = 0U; i < max; ++i) {
                    if (std::string text{}; std::getline(is, text)) tat.texts.push_back(std::move(text));
                }
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
};



int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it is open
    if (std::fstream myfile("r:\\file.txt"); myfile) {

        // Read all data from the source file. One-liner
        std::vector tats(std::istream_iterator<TagAndTexts>(myfile), {});
        // Show just read data on the screen
        std::copy(tats.begin(), tats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TagAndTexts>(std::cout, ""));

        // Get a new entry from the user
        std::cout << "\n\nEnter new data. 1. Tag,  2. Number of texts,  3. each text:\n";
        if (TagAndTexts newData{}; std::cin >> newData) {

            // Add it to our list
            tats.push_back(std::move(newData));
            // Show just read data on the screen
            std::copy(tats.begin(), tats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TagAndTexts>(std::cout, ""));

            // Write new file to disk
            myfile.clear();
            myfile.seekp(0);
            std::copy(tats.begin(), tats.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TagAndTexts>(myfile, ""));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope, this gives you an idea, of how it could be done. Of course there are other possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

While you can get as elaborate as you like, you basic task is to fill an object storing the `tag` and then a vector of strings for the number of strings specified on the next line after the `tag`. The task is more one of how to validate the read of each `tag` and then the specified number of strings associated with that `tag`. To coordinate the storage of the data, you simply need an object storing the `tag` and the vector of strings. A simply `stuct` will do, e.g.

```
struct content {
    std::string tag;                    /* storage for tag */
    std::vector<std::string> str;       /* storage for each string */
};
```

To handle all your data, you will simply declare a `std::vector<content>` and then use a temporary instance of `content` to fill with the data from your file and then `.push_back()` the temporary struct to your vector when you have complete the read for the strings for that `tag`.

To keep yourself straight on which tag you are reading data for you will open you file and read your first line which contains the first `tag`, e.g.

```
    ...
    std::string line;                       /* storage to read each line */
    std::vector<content> contents {};       /* vector of content */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);              /* open file from 1st argument */

    while (getline (f, line)) {             /* read tag line */
        int nstr = 0;                       /* int for num strings */
        content tmp {};                     /* temp struct to fill */
        tmp.tag = line;                     /* set .tag in temp struct */
```

With your `tag` stored in your temporary struct, read the next line into an `int` (or `size_t`) value (don't forget to ignore to end-of-line to remove the `'\n'` left in the input stream):

```
        if (!(f >> nstr)) {                 /* read no. strings as int */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - nstr.\n";
            return 1;
        }   /* ingore to end of line after nstr read as int */
        f.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

With the number of strings for that tag stored as an `int`, simply loop that number of times reading the strings associated with that tag and add them to the vector of strings in your temporary struct (don't forget to validate each read):

```
        while (nstr--) {                    /* loop nstr times */
            if (getline (f, line))          /* read line */
                tmp.str.push_back(line);    /* add to strings stored in temp */
            else {  /* early EOF reached */
                std::cerr << "error: early EOF.\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

After looping and reading each string into the temporary struct, simply `.push_back()` the temporary struct into your permanent storage and you are done:

```
        contents.push_back(tmp);            /* add tmp to contents */
    }
```

Now you have your vector of `content` filled, you can make use of the data any way you like. Outputting the strings under the `tag` as you requested, you can use a nested pair of range-based `for` loops to format it nicely for output:

```
    for (auto& c : contents) {              /* loop over each struct */
        std::cout << "\ntag: " << c.tag << '\n';    /* output tag */
        for (auto& s : c.str)               /* loop over each string */
            std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';         /* output string */
    }
```

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

struct content {
    std::string tag;                    /* storage for tag */
    std::vector<std::string> str;       /* storage for each string */
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;                       /* storage to read each line */
    std::vector<content> contents {};       /* vector of content */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);              /* open file from 1st argument */

    while (getline (f, line)) {             /* read tag line */
        int nstr = 0;                       /* int for num strings */
        content tmp {};                     /* temp struct to fill */
        tmp.tag = line;                     /* set .tag in temp struct */
        if (!(f >> nstr)) {                 /* read no. strings as int */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - nstr.\n";
            return 1;
        }   /* ingore to end of line after nstr read as int */
        f.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        while (nstr--) {                    /* loop nstr times */
            if (getline (f, line))          /* read line */
                tmp.str.push_back(line);    /* add to strings stored in temp */
            else {  /* early EOF reached */
                std::cerr << "error: early EOF.\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        contents.push_back(tmp);            /* add tmp to contents */
    }

    for (auto& c : contents) {              /* loop over each struct */
        std::cout << "\ntag: " << c.tag << '\n';    /* output tag */
        for (auto& s : c.str)               /* loop over each string */
            std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';         /* output string */
    }
}
```

(you can overload `>>` to make the read into your temporary struct a one-shot deal, but the code will essentially be the same, just moved into a member function for `content` that overloads `>>`. That is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file saved as `dat/2darrtags.txt`, you would do:

```
$ ./bin/read2darrtags dat/2darrtags.txt

tag: 1A
  Hi World

tag: 2A
  Hello Bob
  Life is Good

tag: 3A
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There is more than one way to do this. This was just one of the more straight-forward procedural ways of doing it that you can then improve upon as desired.